# Measurable functions in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: measure-theory

I understand how to prove that a function in one variable is measurable from the following definition:

A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, or $\Sigma-$measurable, if the set $ \{x:f(x)>a \} \in \Sigma$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am also aware that this is the same as showing that ${f^{-1}(a,\infty)} \in \Sigma$.

However, I am confused as to how to show that a function such as the following is measurable with respect to the measurable space $(\mathbb{R^2},B_2)$ where $B_2$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R^2}$:

$\phi:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$\phi(x,y)=x$.

It seems to be the introduction of the $\mathbb{R^2}$ that is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Choose some $a$, and look at $A= \{ (x,y) | \phi(x,y) > a \} = \{ (x,y) | x > a \} = (a,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$.

Is the latter set Borel measurable?

Comment: I want to say yes but I don't think I fully understand it.

Comment: The answer depends on how you define the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. One way is to define them as belonging to the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the 'rectangles', that is sets of the form $R_1 \times R_2$ where $R_1,R_2$ are (one dimensional) Borel measurable. With this definition it follows that $A$ is (two dimensional) Borel measurable since $(a,\infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are (one dimensional) Borel measurable.